# determine and change sed column

Tags: sed

I have a file with 3 columns, separated by commas and enclosed by square brackets..:

I would like to change the entries ending with "e-3*" to "0" in all lines.

```
[6.902532920683853e-31,42,27.600000381469727],
[6.902532920683853,42e-31,27.600000381469727],
[6.902532920683853e,42,27.600000381469727e-32],
```

to

```
[0,42,27.600000381469727],
[6.902532920683853,0,27.600000381469727],
[6.902532920683853e,42,0],
```

I tried sed, but I don't know how to address the columns.

This works for the 1st column, but deletes the 1st column in the 2nd row
and the 1st and 2nd column in the 3rd row.

`cat columns.test |sed 's/[0-9].*e-31/0/'`

```
[0,42,27.600000381469727],
[0,27.600000381469727],
[0],
```

Comment: One challenge here is that `sed` doesn't understand columns. So with the current accepted answer, you're matching the pattern anywhere on the line, not just in one column. If you need real CSV support, `sed` is not the tool. You could doo this easily in `awk` though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your pattern is too general for what you want. I managed to get the the expected output by using the following:

```
sed -r 's/(\[|,)[0-9]+(:?\.[0-9]+)?e\-[0-9]+/\10/g'
```

It's probably not the most effecient pattern, but it should cover your use case.

You can see it woking [here](https://regexr.com/7stp8), but the idea is that it'll match an opening square bracket or a comma, then any string of digits (optionally with a decimal point) that ends in "e-" followed by 1 or more digits. That all gets replaced with a reference to the first match (the open bracket "[" or comma ",") followed by a literal "0".

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]\.)?[0-9]+e-3[0-9]*/0/g' file
```

This will match an optional decimal followed by one or digits, followed by `e-3`, followed by  one or more digits and replace the match by 0, globally throughout the file.

N.B. The `-E` command line option to reduce the visual complexity of the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/[0-9.]*e-3[0-9]*/0/g' file
[0,42,27.600000381469727],
[6.902532920683853,0,27.600000381469727],
[6.902532920683853e,42,0],
```